# Android support library 27.1.0 breaks shared element transitions

Tags: android-support-library, shared-element-transition

I have a shared element transition on an ImageView transitioning between list and detail layouts. It works perfectly with support library 27.0.2. However, with support library 27.1.0, on returning from the detail to the list, the image transitions randomly to either the right place or a place higher up the list (it works correctly approximately one time in three).
I don't see anything related in the 27.1.0 release notes.

Code for list:

```
String transitionName = "transition_" + item_id;
imgView.setTransitionName(transitionName);
// Set the tag so the view can be found when the list activity is returned to.
imgView.setTag(transitionName);
:
:
// Start the detail activity with a shared element transition
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                        activity,
                        imgView,
                        transitionName)
                        .toBundle();
activity.startActivity(intent, bundle);
```

Code for detail:

```
String transitionName = "transition_" + item_id;
imgViewInDetail.setTransitionName(transitionName);
```

Comment: It turns out I hadn't implemented postponeEnterTransition() and startPostponedEnterTransition() correctly.  The newer version of the support library must have introduced an extra delay or changed how views were recycled, leading to the observed problem.